# No me funciona el comando tsc de Typescript en la terminal Visual Studio code pero si en mi terminal de windows

Tags: nodejs, typescript, vscode

He seguido los pasos para poder usar typescript en visual studio code.

- Tengo instalado el nodejs con la version 12.14.0,
- Tengo el visual studio code actualizado
- Ejecute el comando "npm install -g typescript" tal como indica en la página 
  principal.

He creado un directorio y al escribir el comando `tsc --init` no me da el siguiente error, tampoco puedo consultar la versión del `tsc` con el comando `tsc -v`.

Pero si uso la terminal de windows, sí me permite utilizar los comandos.

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En vscode te está lanzado el PowerShell. Configúralo para que use cmd.exe.

Comment: Prueba cerrando el visual studio code y volviendolo a abrir, posiblemente aún no reconoce la instalación de typescript y de preferencia usa el cmd como terminal por defecto.